# How to iterate through nodes and display them as a template

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

Like suppose i have 10 shader nodes , so code will check first how many nodes does selected object has then it creates operator for each one of them

Like 10 nnodes so we will have 10 buttons in the tools panel ,

So when we press anyof those button it will display nodes template

So basicall can any body point me in the right direction , like how do i iterate through nodes , anything that might come handy in learning

Answer (score 3):

Here's the quickest way possible

```
for node in bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes:
    print (node)
```